How to pass the result of an array formula to a custom function?
I have a custom function which calculates linearly interpolated values with a specific base value, accounting for that base value and reducing the total to be the same as if the base value was 0. I calculate its t value inside the argument parentheses, and this seems to be the issue.
I want to make it work within array formulae, but the function refuses to work if its t value is calculated within the argument parentheses. It works if I pre-calculate the t values in a separate column and just reference that range, but I'd like to avoid having to do that for the amount of different places I need to use this function in.
Here's the function in question, it is adapted from this solution:
Function BasedLerp(a As Single, b As Single, t As Variant) As Variant
    Dim r() As Single
    Dim i As Integer

    'THIS FUNCTION APPROXIMATES THE SAME SUM OF VALUES AS IF IT WAS A 'Lerp(0,b,t)' FUNCTION, BY ACCOUNTING FOR 'a' BEING NON-ZERO
    
    aVal = (a - (b / 2)) * 2 'The Function works on the [-1 ,1] range, this adjust a [0,1] input
    x = (aVal - b) / 2
    
    If Not (isArray(t)) Then
        BasedLerp = (aVal + ((b - aVal) * t)) - x
    ElseIf TypeOf t Is Excel.Range Then
        ReDim r(1 To t.Cells.Count)
        For i = 1 To t.Cells.Count
            r(i) = (aVal + ((b - aVal) * t.Cells(i).Value)) - x
        Next i

        If t.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            BasedLerp = r
        Else
            BasedLerp = Application.Transpose(r)
        End If
    Else
        ReDim r(LBound(t) To UBound(t))
        For i = LBound(t) To UBound(t)
            r(i) = (aVal + ((b - aVal) * t(i))) - x
        Next i

        BasedLerp = r
    End If

End Function

The way I want to use it is
=BasedLerp([base value];1;(H14:H36/I14:I36))

And it throws #Value errors
If I changed it to
=BasedLerp([base value];1;(H14:H36))

It would work, but that requires me pre-calculating the t values in the range in question, it would add dozens of unnecessary columns in my sheet.
Is this possible? My current assumption is that the return value of (H14:H36/I14:I36) is not accounted for in the script, but I can't find any documentation on what the return type and format of it would be.

Hmmm, what about just calling it like BasedLerp([base value];1;(H14:H36),(I14:I36)) and you can do the division in the function?

Try to change this line r(i) = (aVal + ((b - aVal) * t(i,1))) - x

When t is the result of an array formula, it is usually a 2D n x m array, not a 1-D vector (an exception is literal arrays, but that is not relevant here). The way to check this is to set a breakpoint on the first line of code in the function, and inspect / Watch the t parameter.

The deep analysis of the code is required to catch the fault.
So, when the function is called with "H14:H36" for t, t becomes the Range. The calculation is performed by the ElseIf branch and the vertical vector is returned.
When the function called with "H14:H36/I14:I36" for t, Excel calculates the expression and t becomes the 2-D array (vertical vector). The calculation drops to the Else branch and t(i) causes the error because t is not the 1-D array. It can be corrected in such way:
    Else
        ReDim r(LBound(t) To UBound(t))
        For i = LBound(t) To UBound(t)
            r(i) = (aVal + ((b - aVal) * t(i, 1))) - x
        Next i

        BasedLerp = Application.Transpose(r)
    End If


Iterating via For Each would also work:

2024-08-19: Thanks to rotabor, for pointing out the errors - I have addressed those.

Function BasedLerp2(a As Single, B As Single, t As Variant) As Variant
    Dim r() As Variant
    Dim values As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim item As Variant

    'THIS FUNCTION APPROXIMATES THE SAME SUM OF VALUES AS IF IT WAS A 'Lerp(0,b,t)' FUNCTION, BY ACCOUNTING FOR 'a' BEING NON-ZERO
    
    aVal = (a - (B / 2)) * 2 'The Function works on the [-1 ,1] range, this adjust a [0,1] input
    x = (aVal - B) / 2
    
    If Not (IsArray(t)) Then
        BasedLerp2 = (aVal + ((B - aVal) * t)) - x
    
    Else
        
        If TypeOf t Is Range Then
            values = t.Cells
        Else
            values = t
        End If
        
        ReDim r(LBound(values) To UBound(values))
        i = LBound(values)
        For Each item In values
            r(i) = (aVal + ((B - aVal) * item)) - x
             i = i + 1
        Next item
        
        If TypeOf t Is Range Then
            If t.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                BasedLerp2 = r
            Else
                BasedLerp2 = Application.Transpose(r)
            End If
        Else
            BasedLerp2 = r
        End If
        
    End If

End Function



ByRef is the default way to pass parameters, thus it does nothing.

Your code does not process =BasedLerp([base value];1;H14:H36).

The function successfully process item as the horizontal vector and returns the horizontal vector as well which is not the expected result.
